# Value of setresult not getting in OnActivityResult of my Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, onactivityresult, start-activity

Im trying to set an image from gallery to imageview in my `Fragment`. Picture is selected using my `GallerUtil` Class given below.

```
profile_home.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
 {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent gallery_Intent = new Intent(getActivity(), GalleryUtil.class);
            startActivityForResult(gallery_Intent, GALLERY_ACTIVITY_CODE);
        }
    });
```

GalleryUtil.class

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        try{
            //Pick Image From Gallery
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_SELECT_IMAGE);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch(requestCode){
            case RESULT_SELECT_IMAGE:

                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
                    try{
                        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                        cursor.moveToFirst();
                        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                        cursor.close();

                        //return Image Path to the Main Activity
                        Intent returnFromGalleryIntent = new Intent();
                        Log.d("pathhh",picturePath);

                        returnFromGalleryIntent.putExtra("picturePath",picturePath);
                        setResult(RESULT_OK,returnFromGalleryIntent);
                        finish();
```

The path of this Image is not getting in my `onActivityResult` of my fragment..So please help me find a solution

My onActivityResult in Fragment --

```
 @Override
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.d("pathhh1","11");

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == GALLERY_ACTIVITY_CODE) {
        Log.d("pathhh","12");

        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            picturePath = data.getStringExtra("picturePath");
            Log.d("pathhh",picturePath);
            //perform Crop on the Image Selected from Gallery
            performCrop(picturePath);
        }
    }

    if (requestCode == RESULT_CROP ) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            selectedBitmap = extras.getParcelable("data");
            //selectedBitmap1=getRoundedCroppedBitmap(selectedBitmap, 50);
            CircleDrawable circle = new CircleDrawable(selectedBitmap,true);
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                profile_home.setBackground(circle);
            else
                profile_home.setBackgroundDrawable(circle);

            // Set The Bitmap Data To ImageView
            // profile_img.setImageBitmap(selectedBitmap1);
            profile_home.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        }
    }
```

Comment: my onActivityResult() is shown above .. please check it

Comment: control is not getting back from Galleryutil class to onActivityResult() in Fragment

Comment: You have to get that control back from GallerUtil class to main activity and then pass it to fragment in onActivityResult

Answer (score 1):

**Write this Code into your MainActivity where Fragment are placed.**

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            for (Fragment fragment : getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()) {
                //Write your fragment name instead of YourFragmentName
                if (fragment instanceof YourFragmentName) {
                    fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: you can not call onActivityResult in fragment if you are calling another activity.